# How to show that $\lim_{|x|\to\infty}x(\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{|t|>\epsilon}\frac{f(x-t)}{t}\ dt)=\int_{\bf R}f$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, harmonic-analysis

In his lecture [notes](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/247a.1.06f/notes4.pdf) on the Hilbert transform, Tao claims without proof that if $f$ is in the Schwartz class, then
$$
\lim_{|x|\to\infty}xHf(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{\bf R}f\tag{*}
$$
where $H$ is the Hilbert transform. Intuitively, the $x$ on the left might "cancel out" the denominator in the definition of $Hf$. A naive attempt of change of variables yields:
$$
x\int_{|t|>\epsilon}\frac{f(x-t)}{t}\ dt
=\int_{\epsilon+x}^\infty\frac{xf(u)}{x-u}\ du
+\int_{-\infty}^{x-\epsilon}\frac{xf(u)}{x-u}\ du.
$$

If "$\lim_{|x|\to\infty}$" can be put inside the integral sign, then we are done. But I don't know how to justify it since I don't have a uniform estimate for $|\frac{x}{x-u}-1|$.

> Would anyone elaborate how ($*$) is done?

---

Here is an excerpt of the notes:

> [image]

Comment: I think there's more of an issue than just putting the $\lim_{|x| \to \infty}$ inside the integral, because there's also a $\lim_{\epsilon \downarrow 0}$ floating around, and so you would first have to switch those two limits.

Comment: Step 1: write $x = (x-u) + u$ in the numerator. Step 2: $u \mapsto uf(u)$ belongs to the Schwartz space. Step 3: $Hg(x) \to 0$ as $\lvert x\rvert \to \infty$ for a Schwartz function $g$.

Comment: Yea that does it

Comment: @DanielFischer Following step 1 and 2 in your comment, one has (if my calculation is correct) $$xHf(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{\bf R}f+Hg(x) $$ where $g(x)=xf(x)$. So it suffices to show Step 3, which must have something to do with the decay property of $g$. But I don't see how. Would you elaborate it?

Comment: We know that $Hg \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$, and that $H(g') = (Hg)' \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$. If $h$ and $h'$ both belong to $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, then it follows that $h \in C_0(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Thanks. I was just about to write a question asking why $H$ maps the Schwartz class to $L^2({\mathbb R})$... (which is the last sentence in the excerpt.) I will work on it and come back later.

Comment: It maps $L^p$ to $L^p$ for $1 < p < \infty$, see the wikipedia article.

Comment: @Jack it's easier to see the special case of mapping into $L^2$, via the fourier transform and plancherel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Daniel Fischer's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2581165/how-to-show-that-lim-x-to-inftyx-lim-epsilon-to-0-int-t-epsilon-f#comment5327620_2581165), I have an answer.

Note that
$$
\pi Hf(x) = \int_{|y-x| > 1} \frac{f(y)}{x-y}\ dy + \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{\epsilon\leq|y-x| \leq 1} \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{x-y}\ dy\tag{2}
$$
This can be show by observing that convolution commutes: $f*g=g*f$ and that
$$
\int_{\epsilon<|y-x| \leq 1} \frac{f(x)}{x-y}\ dy=0
$$
by "symmetry".

Since we have the pointwise limit:
$$
\lim_{|x|\to\infty}1_{|x-y|>1}(y)\frac{f(y)}{x-y}=0,
$$
dominated convergence shows that the first term on the RHS of (2) is gone as $|x|\to\infty$. On the other hand, the mean value theorem implies that the absolute value of the second term can be controlled by
$$
2|f'(\xi_x)|,\quad \xi_x\in (x-1,x+1),
$$
which goes to $0$ as $|x|\to\infty$ since $f$ is in the Schwartz space $\mathcal{S}({\bf R})$. We have thus shown that

> for any function $f\in\mathcal{S}({\bf R})$, $\lim_{|x|\to\infty}Hf(x)=0$.

Now note that<sup>1</sup>
$$
xHf(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{\bf R}f+Hg(x),
$$
where $g(x)=xf(x)\in\mathcal{S}({\bf R})$. We are done.

---

<sup>1</sup> Observe that
$$
x\int_{|t|>\epsilon}\frac{f(x-t)}{t}\ dt
=\int_{|u-x|>\epsilon}\frac{x-u}{x-u}\cdot f(u)\ du
+\int_{|u-x|>\epsilon}\frac{u\cdot f(u)}{x-u}\ du.
$$